# Complexity of inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert, insert-update

[image: ERD]

My issue with an old customer plus outdated system.Part of issue.  The 3 tables contain existing data in database. Let me explain, what was the scenario and then I hope you guys can help me get this job done.

**Scenario** :

- There were a lot of Product, especially ProductZone, as you might imagine...
- Customer add new Zone(let’s assume **new Zone U,V,W,X,Y,Z**),unfortunately did not for ProductZone!
- Costomer need to update(insert) ProductZones to make all existing Products refer with new Zones and some older Zones(let’s assume **older Zone R,S,T**) if it didn't exist,here I came across...,need your help!

**Explanation** :

If i understand correctly i have to massive insert ProductZone and in this case by complicate T-SQL both filter condition and insert statement.

I'd be glad to take any suggestions,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will populate the Zones for existing products available in ProductZone Table and the new products available in Product table.

```
INSERT   INTO ProductZone 
SELECT ZoneNo, 
       ProductNo 
FROM   Product a 
       CROSS JOIN ZONE b 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   ProductZone c 
                   WHERE  a.ProductNo = c.ProductNo 
                          AND a.zone = c.zone)
```

Comment: It's worth adding make a backup of your database before you run a query. That way you are safe.

Comment: @Romil Excellent,you really helped me out